Databricks Asset Bundles: use multiple yml files containing jobs
I have two yml files containing jobs, which are located in the resources folder.
Each file starts with
resources:
  jobs:

In my databricks.yml file I do the following:
include:
  - resources/**/*.yml

When running databricks deploy, it seems like only one of the file gets deployed. How can I distribute my jobs over multiple files?

Keep multiple yml files under resources folder and add below piece in the databricks.yml
include:
   - resources/*.yml


when runnig it i get
Error: cannot update job: Shared job cluster feature is only supported in multi-task jobs.
When import folder by folder it works
e.g.

resources/*.yml
resources/test/*.yml

